# django-allauth socialaccount not logging in?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-allauth

I've recently switched server/database and am having trouble getting the google and facebook social apps to log in. I have the keys set up correctly and when hitting both facebook and google it successfully creates a django user and a social account, but it does not log the user in. Notably, it sends the user to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` correctly.

When attempting to sign in with an existing user after it has already been created, it also does not log in, but also sends to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` correctly.

I can't figure out why it is behaving this way in the new environment, and am struggling on finding where to look. My best guess is that somewhere the pre_social_login signal or the social_account_added signal? Any ideas?

EDIT:
Also worth noting, I switched from python 3.4 to python 2.7, but django remained 1.6.5

Comment: `it does not log the user in !` what is the error here.? or can i assume like after authentication user send automatically to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` ..?

Comment: There is no error :( it loads the redirect url (which is just the home page) without any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I was missing the allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend in the settings `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` when i did the migrate.